# Unable to create Derby connection pool in Payara-6 server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, derby, payara

I am trying to create a Derby connection pool in Payara-6 server. I tried creating it twice: once with vendor "Derby" and once with "Derby-30" (not sure about the differences). These were the following values that I set:

```
Resource Type: java.sql.Driver
Datasource Classname: <empty>
Driver classname: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

I have also set the URL, user, & password for the DB. But, when I try to ping the DB< I get the following error:
[image]

I do have the derby jars locally in my machine, but I do not believe that the same is available to the payara server. Please help in debugging the same.

Answer (score 1):

Payara doesn’t include Derby driver. You need to add Derby DB JARs into Payara, for example into the lib directory in the domain directory.

If you did it, try setting the following parameters to the connection pool:

Resource type: javax.sql.DataSource

Datasource classname: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource

You can also try Eclipse GlassFish 7, which includes Derby DB, and even uses it for the default connection pool. You can copy the configuration from GlassFish to Payara, as long as you have the correct Derby JARs to Payara too.